# Why datepicker is attaching with every input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a webpage where I want to attach datepicker to all input fields of id `schedule`, but it attaching the datepicker with all input fields of the page.

**[Note: I have removed my web addresses for security issue as my problem has already been resolved. Thanks to all of you]**

the function for datepicker is:

```
$('#schedule  input').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function ()
        {
            var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //alert(date2);
            var targetInputs = null;
            var eventFromAll = false;

            if($(this).attr("id") == "all")
            {
                targetInputs = $('input');
                eventFromAll = true;
            }
            else
                targetInputs = $(this).closest("tr").find('input');

            $(targetInputs).not(this).each(function (i, op)
            {
                var c = $(this).attr('c');
                var d = parseInt($(this).attr('d'), 10);

                if (c == 'y') {
                    date2.setFullYear(date2.getFullYear() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'd') {
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'm') {
                    date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + d);
                }

                   $(this).datepicker('setDate', date2);
            });
        }
    });
```

What I want, the `#schedule` table is generating dynamically while page loads and I want to attach the datepicker only to the input fields which are inside `#schedule` table. As for example, if you select a date from `1st Dose` Column, it changes dates in `2nd/3rd/4th` Columns. But you can see, that with every input field of the page, such as the `Search:` input field or even `button input` field, the datepicker is attaching. As a result, when I click and close the datepicker on `Search` input box, the datepicker changes the text of `button` input.

I don't know why this is happening. How can I limit the attachment of datepicker to only the input field under `#schedule` table?

Comment: Why downvote? Somebody is giving me downvote in every post I am creating. Moderator please look at this point. Please ban those users who are giving me downvote without any explanation.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique in HTML page.  If you want to add date picker for many input fields use class names for all of them. this is the basic html concept so people downvote this kind of questions.

Comment: I have changed the selector as `table.print > tbody> tr > td > input`, but it is not working, it is still attaching datepicker to every input field. Do you check the `jquery-ui.js` script whether it is the culprit or not?

Comment: issue is not with jquery ui js , it is with you code , you better provide a fiddle

Comment: @wero already have figured it out in which place of my code was creating this problem and I have resolved this issue. Thankyou very much for your comment. @J Santosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 230 in http://infomamun.swapnoit.com/schedule.php?ckattempt=1 reads:

```
$('input').datepicker({..
```

This is executed on page load and therefore a datepicker is attached to every input element on the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually it was my fault. I was attaching the script in two places of my page mistakenly (one is in head of the page, and other is as a javascript source file). I was editing the source javascript file but did not look at the head section. That's why it was happening. Thank you very much for figuring it out. Now it is all okay.